# Delete Visual Studio solution folders

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dotnetnuke

I have Viusal Studio 2008 on my PC at work and Visual Studio Express 2010 installed on my PC at home.

I have downloaded some source code from the Internet (DotNetNuke) and I am trying to step through it on my PC at home.  The problem is that the DotNetNuke source code uses Solution folders and the express editions do not support them.  When I open the solution I am faced with errors for every project that is part of a solution.

Is there a way of deleting the solution folders by editing a configuration file, without deleting the projects that are part of the solution folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is but you have to be careful. Open the .SLN file in something like notepad++/notepad. And just remove the the references to the solution folder. Then move the .SLN file to the folder with the code.

Comment: I think you mean the .SLN file

Comment: Sorry yes I do a typo from my phone.